# Windows 8 store app : compress jpeg, resize it

Tags: resize, compression, bitmapimage

I develop a w8 store application.
I want to compress & resize a bitmapimage before send it over azure.
So here is my code :

```
                using (var sourceStream = await sfile.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    // affect BitmapImage
                    Image = new BitmapImage();
                    Image.SetSource(sourceStream);



                }
```

My question :

- How to compress the bitmapImage ?
- How to resize the bitmapImage ?
- How to get byte[] from this compressed and resized bitmapImage ?

Thanks !